# How to convert google cloud virtual machine external ip from http to https?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have a compute instance running apache server for showcasing a dashboard. I wanted to embed the dashboard in my website using Iframe. But the default IP address of the compute engine is in HTTP and not https.

Please let me know how i can change this to https?

Answer (score 5):

HTTP and HTTPS don't depend on the IP. IP is a low level network routing (layer 3) and the HTTP(s) is an higher protocol (layer 7). See [OSI layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

You simply have to install a [SSL certificate](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) on your Apache server to serve content on HTTPS.

However, on Google Cloud, I recommend you to put an HTTP load balancer in front of your VM, to let it in HTTP, and to configure the HTTPS directly on the load balancer. Google can manage (generate, install and renew) for you.